# List IPv6 Neighbor Proxies in Linux

Tags: linux, ipv6

With the command like these the following you can add neighbor proxies in Linux

```
ip -6 neigh add proxy 2001:db8:100:3022:1::4 dev eth0
```

Is there a way how to list which proxies have already been defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
ip -6 neigh show proxy
```

It works for me:

```
emily ~ # ip -6 neigh add proxy 2001:db8:100:3022:1::4 dev eth0
emily ~ # ip -6 neigh show proxy
2001:db8:100:3022:1::4 dev eth0  proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

On some distribution "ip -6 neigh show proxy" doesn't work but your can see the corresponding multicast address to be answered :

```
ip -6 maddr show
```